# Javascript regex to bold multiple strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to bold the following words in a string, but I can't get the syntax right, can anyone explain how to do this with multiple keywords please.

```
reg = /(^|\s) vomiting | foodpoisoning | food poisoning | poisoned | diarrhoea | diarrhea | sick | puking | puked (\s|$)/ig ;

review = review.replace((reg,'$1<b>$2</b>$3'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like this:

```js
var re = /\b(vomiting|food ?poisoning|poisoned|diarrho?ea|sick|puking|puked)\b(?!<\/b>)/g; 
var str = 'There was some sick man, sick child and an already <b>sick</b> woman.';
var subst = '<b>$1</b>'; 
alert(str.replace(re, subst));
```

Your regex contains unnecessary spaces as I see you were trying to match word boundaries with them and `(^|\s)` and `(\s|$)`. Word boundaries are matched with `\b`. Also, I placed the alternatives into a capturing group so that `\b` on both sides are applied to both sides of the words matched.

The `(?!<\/b>)` lookahead will make sure we are not adding the bold tags to already bolded word.

Also, you can shorten the list a bit using `?` quantifiers.

If matching does not have to be case sensitive, replace `/g` with `/gi` at the end of the regex.

Comment: Awesome thanks! That is exactly what i was looking for and didn't know about quantifiers so thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually, you can also make use of character classes to account for word variants (like `gr[ae]y`), but that is fine-tuning already :).